# semantic in emacs does not find fopen

Tags: emacs

When I type 'f' in a C source file, my emacs with semantic installed and working
will show 25 completion matches, for functions like fclose, fread, and so on (only stdio.h
included)... but not fopen! Why?
Plus, same problem with opendir and readdir, with sys/types.h and dirent.h included.

P.S. semantic has all my sympathy, as upon my personal reading glibc header files showed
as a horrible mess of #ifnded and alikes.

Answer (score 1):

'fopen' is turning up fine for me. Are you by any chance working on OS X? I remember that there were some preprocessor macros there which confused Semantic. Otherwise, your best chance for help is posting to the CEDET-devel mailing list, stating the CEDET version you're using and posting the exact definition of the 'fopen' function which apparently cannot be parsed.

Comment: No, I'm on Ubuntu. Anyway I'll try your suggestion.